# Multiplying arrays of matrices in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a data set that consists of two 1800 x 900 x 3 x 3 arrays, which should each be interpreted as a 1800x900 array of 3x3 matrices. As part of the analysis, at one point I need to create another such array by, at each point of the 1800x900 array, multiplying the corresponding 3x3 matrices together.

There seem to be two ways to do this that I can think of. The obvious way is

```
C = zeros(size(A))
for i = 1:900
    for j = 1:1800
        C(i,j,:,:) = A(i,j,:,:)*B(i,j,:,:)
    end
end
```

But that's quite a long loop and doesn't really take advantage of MATLAB's vectorization. The other way is

```
C = zeros(size(A))
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        for k = 1:3
            C(:,:,i,j) = C(:,:,i,j) + A(:,:,i,k).*B(:,:,k,j)
        end
    end
end
```

where the large dimensions are getting vectorized and I'm basically using the for loops to implement the Einstein summation convention. This seems really inelegant, though, which makes me think there should be a better way. Is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect job for [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
C = permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, permute(B, [1 2 5 3 4])), 4), [1 2 3 5 4]);
```

In R2016b onwards you can avoid `bsxfun` thanks to [implicit singleton expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/):

```
C = permute(sum(A .* permute(B, [1 2 5 3 4]), 4), [1 2 3 5 4]);
```

Comment: You might need to explain to me in more detail what's going on with that code. I haven't used bsxfun or permute before. And I suppose I forgot the squeezes in my first example didn't I?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Regarding `bsxfun`, it would be hard for me to explain it better than in the [linked post](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/). Please read it and let me know if you have any questions. `permute` is used here to "align" the dimensions so that singleton expansion takes place as needed

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, you forgot `squeeze`. Or better yet use `permute`.  In your case it doesn't matter, but if the matrices were `1`x`3` instead of `3`x`3` the `squeeze` function would turn `A(i,j,:,:)` (size `1`x`1`x `1`x`4`) into `4`x`1`, not `1`x`4` as required. So use `permute(..., [3 4 1 2])` to move dimensions third and fourth to the "front"

Comment: Oh so you are turning the 3rd (1st) dimension of B (a regular 3x3 matrix) by 90 degrees, finding the element-wise product, and then summing it with respect to 4th (2nd) dim of A (another regular matrix) and 3rd (1st) dim of B. That's brilliant!